# Can I combine parts of multiple columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a student in college and I'm working on a project with Oracle DB. I was wondering if it was possible to make a column value appear as concatenated parts of other columns when I Insert a line and use that column as PK ?

So on a table like this :

```sql
CREATE TABLE Cellphone (
    id          VARCHAR (8) PRIMARY KEY,
    maker       VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    range       VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    model       VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    ram         NUMBER (2)     NOT NULL,
    color       VARCHAR (5)    NOT NULL,
    quantity    NUMBER (3)     DEFAULT 0
);
```

So when I insert a line I'd like the id to be set automatically to a concatenated value of the first 3 character of the maker, the first 3 of the range, the first 3 of the model, the ram and the color.

For example :

```sql
INSERT INTO Cellphone (id, maker, range, model, ram, color, quantity)
VALUES (*The code I am looking for*, "SAMSUNG", "GALAXY", "S10",32,"BLK",56);
```

The `id` that would be generated is `SAMGALS1032BLK`.

Is it possible to do that?  If not is there something that could look like that, maybe with a SELECT statement when I want to show the table?

Comment: having id as a string is not a good option ,even your id will have data with some logic only. so i would suggest you to make this column to unique key and create another column  as integer that should be primary key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Cellphone (
    id          AS (substr(maker,0,3)||substr(range,0,3)||model||ram||color) PRIMARY KEY,
    maker       VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    range       VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    model       VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    ram         NUMBER (2)     NOT NULL,
    color       VARCHAR (5)    NOT NULL,
    quantity    NUMBER (3)     DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO Cellphone (maker, range, model, ram, color, quantity)
VALUES ('SAMSUNG', 'GALAXY', 'S10',32,'BLK',56);

select * from Cellphone;
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=954fb222fba8a2b49c3937c47e9f4726

Comment: It's a great answer (+1) - I didn't know it!

Comment: Thank you Fahmi ! Appreciate your comments !

Comment: @Fahmi, If I am not wrong this is also know as `virtual column` introduced in Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, thanks for the info. I don't know much about Oracle, but I'll search for this.

Comment: @Soumendra Mishra, just curious is there any difference just saying `as` or `generated always as` ?

Comment: As per documentation: ` The GENERATED ALWAYS and VIRTUAL keywords are provided for clarity only`

Comment: Documentation Link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1